# FeignClients get published as REST endpoints in spring cloud application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I've got REST `FeignClient` defined in my application:

```
@FeignClient(name = "gateway", configuration = FeignAuthConfig.class)
public interface AccountsClient extends Accounts {

}
```

I share endpoint interface between server and client:

```
@RequestMapping(API_PATH)
public interface Accounts {


    @PostMapping(path = "/register",
            produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<?> registerAccount(@RequestBody ManagedPassUserVM managedUserDTO)
            throws EmailAlreadyInUseException, UsernameAlreadyInUseException, URISyntaxException;

}
```

Everythng works fine except that my `FeignClient` definition in my client application also got registered as independent REST endpoint.

At the moment I try to prevent this behavior using filter which returns `404` status code for `FeignClinet` client mappings in my client application. However this workeraund seems very inelegant.

Is there another way how to prevent feign clients registering as separate REST endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known limitation of Spring Cloud's feign support. By adding `@RequestMapping` to the interface, Spring MVC (not Spring Cloud) assumes you want as an endpoint. `@RequestMapping` on Feign interfaces is not currently supported.

Comment: It seems like a bug in SpringMvc. I also tried to omit my FeignClients from component scaning and it didn't work.

Comment: Pretty sure it's been a feature for a fairly long time. It is a shortcut, so you don't have to put both `@RequestMapping` and `@Component`.

Comment: It seems that they forgot to mention this behavior in documentation or javadoc. It also seems as quite unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've used workaround for this faulty Spring Framework behavior:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({Feign.class})
public class FeignMappingDefaultConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcRegistrations feignWebRegistrations() {
        return new WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter() {
            @Override
            public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                return new FeignFilterRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
            }
        };
    }

    private static class FeignFilterRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {
        @Override
        protected boolean isHandler(Class<?> beanType) {
            return super.isHandler(beanType) && (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanType, FeignClient.class) == null);
        }
    }
}
```

I found it in SpringCloud [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/466)